# Selenium Grid does not work with IE11

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, selenium-grid, geb

Selenium Grid (selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1) does not work with IE 11 on Win7 32Bit node.
IE browser window is opened, but the test is not executed. Only the message "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." is displayed in IE.

Option "caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true)" is set in the GEB/Groovy framework.

FF and Chrome tests on the node are working without any problem.

For IE tests only the browser window is opened. No error message is shown in the grid.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide the command line you used to launch your Windows node. Did you add the required registry key for Windows? Is the browser zoom level set to 100%?

Comment: Command launching the node: java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.firefox.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=seleniumuser -jar C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://192.168.1.67:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,platform=WINDOWS" -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS

Comment: In GebConfig.groovy I have:             remoteDriver.manage().window().maximize()

Comment: Where should I set the zoom level? Which registry keys need to be set? I am on a 32 bit win7 node.

Comment: Please consider updating your question, making the problem reproduceable with a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Then maybe you can also get better help.

Comment: If someone has a working setup with IE11 in the selenium grid I would be happy to check that configuration. IE11 simply does not work on any MS node, win7, 8.1, 10 using selenium grid. I tried going backwards using version 2.x.x, but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some required configuration for the Internet Explorer Driver, and even for Internet Explorer 11.

Here is the link to the official documentation: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did everything as written here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration, but no change, IE opens, no tests are executed, IE remains open forever.